# How to install ionCube loader on HEROKU

Tags: php, heroku, ioncube

I'm migrating a website from a shared host to Heroku. The main problem that I'm facing right now is that the web solution we are using, GEODESIC SOLUTIONS, can't continue without ionCube Loader installed.

**[This is the site](http://www.nakitu.ch/core/admin/)**

The wizard that the ionCube Loader provided in the instructions requires FTP, but I don't know how to do that with heroku.

If anyone is kind enough to help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can install ionCube loaders on shared host manually. You probably have to contact technical support and they might be able to do it for you.

Unless you have full root access and you are able to edit php.ini etc.

Comment: I'm migrating my website to Heroku, heroku is not a shared host. I am fully aware of what you are saying, I am simply asking if there is a way to install it on heroku which uses GIT as a deployment mechanism

Comment: It is not possible to use FTP with Heroku

Comment: I know that FTP is not possible with Heroku, that is why I am asking if there is another way to install IonCube in Heroku.

Comment: @Wot you can install the Loader on many shared hosts manually, GoDaddy for example; basically any that supports custom php.ini files. Provided that the Heroku platform allows editing the php.ini file, which it should as being able to do so is important for setting up any serious web application, there's every chance that the OP will be in luck.